# What is the difference between keras.activations.softmax and keras.layers.Softmax?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, softmax, activation-function

What is the difference between `keras.activations.softmax` and `keras.layers.Softmax`? Why are there two definitions of the same activation function?

`keras.activations.softmax`: https://keras.io/activations/

`keras.layers.Softmax`: https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are equivalent to each other in terms of what they do. Actually, the `Softmax` layer would call the `activations.softmax` [under the hood](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/920e8af34a43ad2cd11190a21200a2acbfd83e11/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py#L253):

```py
def call(self, inputs):
    return activations.softmax(inputs, axis=self.axis)
```

However, their difference is that the `Softmax` layer could be directly used as a layer:

```py
from keras.layers import Softmax

soft_out = Softmax()(input_tensor)
```

But, `activations.softmax` could not be used directly as a layer. Rather, you can pass it as the activation function of other layers through `activation` argument:

```py
from keras import activations

dense_out = Dense(n_units, activation=activations.softmax)
```

Further, note that the good thing about using `Softmax` layer is that it takes an `axis` argument and you can compute the softmax over another axis of the input instead of its last axis (which is the default):

```py
soft_out = Softmax(axis=desired_axis)(input_tensor)
```

Comment: But Softmax layer cannot specify precision, which means that if I use mixed precision and a Softmax layer as the output layer, I cannot convert float16 back into float32 that is request by tf in order to preserve accuracy in loss (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision#training_the_model_with_a_custom_training_loop). Any work-around? Thanks.